# Using .htaccess to redirect www URLs to non-www for https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl

Please provide me with .htaccess syntax to do the following:

1. Redirect from **http** to **https**
2. Redirect from **https://www.domain.com.uk** to **https://domain.com.uk**

I tried the following but it didn't work:

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.(.*)
>
> RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to your htaccess file in the root folder of your domain.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if not domain.com.uk then redirect to domaim.com.uk
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://domain.com.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#if not https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#redirect to https
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: It worked properly for redirect http to https

But it didn't redirect from www.domain.com.uk to domain.com.uk

Comment: @RamyAllam Do you have any other rules in your .htacccess file? Are the rules exactly as above, and in that order? If either one is different, then it could affect the result

Comment: I don't have any other rules in .htaccess, And i added this with the same syntax.. Also i tried to put it directly into httpd.conf

<Directory "/home/user/public_html">

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

#if not domain.com.uk then redirect to domaim.com.uk

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com\.uk$ [NC]

RewriteRule .* http://domain.com.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#if not https

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

#redirect to https

RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</Directory>

and it didn't work as well.

Comment: @RamyAllam it looks like you are missing the `http://` in the redirect i.e it should be `RewriteRule .* http://domain.com.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`.  It will not work without it.

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't understand your last comment.
I hope to give me more details or type the full syntax
Thanks

Comment: I added the same of your syntax in httpd.conf 
<Directory "/home/user/public_html">
syntax here 
</Directory>
May be http:// didn't appear in my above comment
It didn't work as well

Comment: Should i by a new SSL certificate for www.domain.com in order for the domain to be redirected to domain.com ?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com.uk
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For me this work, just tested. So `http://www.domain.com.uk into https://domain.com.uk` .